# Is it possible to filter kontent results (delivery api) by linked item type

Tags: kentico-kontent

Is it possible to filter and only bring back content items what have a linked-item of type x e.g.

I have 3 content type A, B, and C

A has a field called subItems which takes either content type A, B or C

How would i construct a query for content-items that have at least one subItem of Content-type B

Answer (score 0):

I think the scenario is not covered right in [filtering operators](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/delivery-api#tag/Filtering-content/filtering-operators).

On the other hand, you could filter out content items with `[any]` filter if you have their codename.

1. Load codenames of `Content-type B`
2. Use `[any]` operator for `subitems` element with loaded codenames

You could load codenames of `Content-type B` items using [/items](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/delivery-api#operation/list-content-items) endpoint.

> To prevent loading data you don't need (in that case you want to ignore all `elements`, you just need codename) you could use [projection feature](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/delivery-api#tag/Projection).
>
> If you have more than 2000 content items (or hitting [response size](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/delivery-api#section/Response-size) any other way) of type B, use [`/items-feed`](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/delivery-api#operation/enumerate-content-items) and load items page by page.

`https://deliver.kontent.ai/<PROJECTID>/items?elements=null&system.type=content_type_b`

And then use [`[any]`](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/delivery-api#tag/Filtering-content/filtering-operators) filter:

`https://deliver.kontent.ai/<PROJECTID>/items?elements.subitems[any]=<codename1>,<codename2>,...`